# How to solve the following IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find all solutions to the following IVP:

$$\dot{x}=x^{2023}-x^{2022}$$
$$ x(0) = 1 $$

I am really not sure how to start this problem, my initial idea was to use the separation of the variables, but no matter how I tried I couldn´t solve it correctly, I would appreciate any kind of help or ideas.

Comment: What are the zeros at the right side? What is the slope at the initial point?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not sure, can you just point me in the right direction?

Comment: To find equilibrium points, factor the right hand side. $x^{2023} - x^{2022} = x^{2022}(x-1)$. Notice that $x=1$ is an equilibrium point.

Comment: Initial condition is bad.

Comment: @mwalth so we get an equilibrium point at $x=1$, but as far as I can see, the point there would be unstable since, for the bigger values than 1, the slope is positive, and for value between 0 and 1 it is negative.

Comment: Show that if $x < 1$ anywhere, then $x < 1$ everywhere. Do the same for $x > 1$. That leaves only one possibility for $x(t)$.

Comment: @variableXYZ, you're right that the equilibrium point is unstable. However, your initial condition puts you right smack dab on the equilibrium point because $x=1$ at time $t=0$. By the definition of equilibrium point, this means that $x(t)=1$ for all $t$. If the initial condition were $x(0)=1.0000001$ then it would be another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying separation-of-variables, the first step is to check the right side for roots. These are easily found as $x^*_0=0$ and $x^*_1=1$. These roots correspond to constant solutions. As the right side is a polynomial, the solutions are unique, no branching or coalescing of solutions can occur.

Thus the initial condition $x(0)=1=x^*_1$ implies directly, without any further calculation, that the one and only solution of the IVP is the constant solution $x(t)=x^*_1=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The ODE can be solved as follows. Separate variables.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^{2023} - x^{2022} \implies \frac{dx}{x^{2022} (x-1)} = dt$$

Expand the left side into partial fractions. It's easy to show (by induction, for instance) that

$$\frac1{x^n (x-1)} = \frac1{x-1} - \left(\frac1x + \frac1{x^2} + \frac1{x^3} + \cdots + \frac1{x^n}\right)$$

It follows that

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2022} (x-1)} = \int dt \implies \ln|x-1| - \ln|x| + \frac1{x} + \frac1{2x^2} + \cdots + \frac1{2021x^{2021}} = t + C$$

As pointed out in comments, however, the given initial value is problematic, since the $\ln|x-1|$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $x\to1$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @user170231's answer, we can make the solution more compact
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{n} (x-1)}= \frac{x^{1-n} }{n-1}\,\, _2F_1(1,1-n;2-n;x)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

This also shows the problem at $x=0$, the limit of the hypergeometric function being equal to $1$